# JQuery Autocomplete with AJAX/php

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

So I've managed to finally get this working and populating the fields, however it seems to be adding in some divs with the results randomly.

```
$(function(){
var $searchBox = $('#titleHome');
$searchBox.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'homeGetCds.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
               searchTerm: request.term,
               row_num : 1
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
        $('#yearHome').val(names[1]);
        $('#priceHome').val(names[2]);
        $('#descHome').val(names[3]);
        $('#publisherHome').val(names[4]);
        $('#locationHome').val(names[5]);
    }
  });
});
```

The php to go with this this is as follows:

```
$cd = $row['CDTitle'].'|'.$row['CDYear'].'|'.$row['CDPrice'].'|'.$row['catDesc'].'|'.$row['pubName'].'|'.$row['location'].'|'.$row_num;
```

When I select a result from the dropdown the "title" (which is the search) also appears in its own `<div>` in a span on the page. It also shows "1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate" when searching

There is a pic here of it happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nicm6.jpg

Comment: cant seem to figure out why its doing this :/

anyone?